# deprecated_string_conv_gen: conversion from a string literal to pointer-to-character (non-const) is deprecated in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

From the coverity tool, I am getting the below warning message in the C++ code:

**deprecated_string_conv_gen: conversion from a string literal to pointer-to-character (non-const) is deprecated**

at the below line:

si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\default";

Could anyone please help me how to resolve this warning message?

**Below is the complete code snippet:**

```
LONG RcRegJob::CreateProcessandExit()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    WCHAR pwszMcSvrCntPath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
    dwExitCode = ::GetModuleFileName(NULL, pwszMcSvrCntPath, MAX_PATH);

    if (dwExitCode)
    {
        std::wstring strFilePath = pwszMcSvrCntPath;
        std::wstring strProcessName;
        int npos = strFilePath.rfind(L"\\");

        strProcessName = strFilePath.substr(npos + 1, strFilePath.length());
        strFilePath = strFilePath.substr(0, npos);

        ::ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        ::ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";

        {
            dwExitCode = ::CreateProcess(0, (LPWSTR)strProcessName.c_str(),
                0, 0, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0,
                strFilePavth, &si, &pi);
        }

        if (0 == dwExitCode)
        {
            dwExitCode = ::GetLastError(); 
        }
        else
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return dwExitCode;
}
```

**Declaration:**

```
LPWSTR  lpDesktop;
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. So pointers that point to string literals shall have the qualifier const that is they shall point to constant objects.

However this data member

```
LPWSTR  lpDesktop;
```

does have the qualifier `const`.

The data member should be declared like

```
LPCWSTR  lpDesktop;
```

To avoid the error you could declare a non-constant array and initialize it with the string literal `L"winsta0\\default"` and then set the pointer to point to this array.

Comment: *So pointers that point to string literals shall have the qualifier const.* reads like you need `type * const`, not `type const *` which is what is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Based on your inputs I changed L"winsta0\\default" to wchar_t *pwdefault = L"winsta0\\default";    si.lpDesktop = pwdefault;